# Fluent assertions - how to properly chain after a type check

Tags: c#, .net, fluent-assertions

Why can't I do the following with FluentAssertions, using the 'And' property?

```
SomeObject.Should()
   .BeAssignableTo<OtherObject>()
   .And
   .SomeStringProperty.Should().StartWith("whatever");
```

That will not compile because after the And it doesn't know that it's a SomeObject type. Instead, I have to use 'Which' in place of And, which I thought was used for collections, not single objects. The Which version does compile but the semantics aren't as clear

Comment: `Which` can be use on collection or single object as well https://fluentassertions.com/introduction

Comment: @Nkosi That page only states "...ability to chain a specific assertion on top of an assertion that acts on a collection or graph of objects", hence my question. I think you are likely right, but some official documentation confirming that or a diff way than using 'Which' would be nice

Answer (score 4):

`Which` will give you a reference to `SomeObject`, but cast as `OtherObject`. So your example will change to:

```
SomeObject.Should()
   .BeAssignableTo<OtherObject>()
   .Which.SomeStringProperty.Should().StartWith("whatever");
```

Comment: yes thats true and what I stated in my question. Was looking for *why* have to use 'Which' instead of 'And' and why their docs state 'Which' is for collections and object graphs

Comment: `And` just returns the assertion class that you started with and on which `BeAssignableTo` is defined. `Which` is available when that particular assertion makes sense and there's some typed object to continue on.